# Folder reference for iOS in Flutter project without using Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a Flutter project with "config" folder in root. This need to copied to iOS folder as "Folder Reference".

I can do this by using Xcode

- Open Xcode
- File -> Add files to "Runner"
- Choose Config folder
- Check "Copy Items if needed" and "Create Folder references"
- Click add

This works. But I would like to automate this process, is there a way to create folder reference in flutter without using/opening Xcode.

Edit:

**Why I need this:**

I am building an Flutter Plugin that uses native myLibrary.Framework and myLibrary.aar

This myLibrary requires config folder in certain path for both Android and iOS.

- For Android I wrote a script that copies this config folder [This works]
- For iOS if I copy to the root folder without using Xcode, it doesn't get detected. [This doesn't work]

Our plugin will be used by other developers, I don't want them manually opening Xcode and making folder references.

How does Xcode track "Folder references". Is it possible to create Folder references via scripts without opening Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Add a parent folder to Xcode, and don't check `Copy Items if needed`， but only `Create Folder references`.

Then you add extra folder in the parent folder, it will appear in Xcode automatic.

Comment: it still requires XCode. Is it possible to eliminate the use of XCode. What happens when we mark a folder as folder reference. Is it possible to do it via command line. Is there some xml files that I can edit to make folder reference.

Comment: It’s one time only

Comment: Thanks, But is it possible to eliminate XCode all together..
I updated the question to match my requirement.

Comment: @SubinSV there’s four line of code if you add folder reference if there’s only one target in Xcode project.

Comment: I was digging around and found similar lines of code in project.pbxproj file. But am not sure how these are generated, these file contains contains some fileRef, but there are some hashes, not sure how to generate them via scripting.

```
  40734EB422EF18C40074FFDE /* assets */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = folder; path = assets; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

Comment: @SubinSV yes they are generated by Xcode  , that’s why better use Xcode generator the first top container folder reference

Comment: Thanks @JerryZhou,
I will check for other possibilities, If not found, I will use the first top container approach. Will also update the post if I find any other solution.